# Sleeping in a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

When writing a batch file to automate something on a Windows box, I've needed to pause its execution for several seconds (usually in a test/wait loop, waiting for a process to start). At the time, the best solution I could find uses ping (I kid you not) to achieve the desired effect. I've found a better write-up of it [here](http://malektips.com/dos0017.html), which describes a callable "wait.bat", implemented as follows:

```
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 1000 > nul
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n %1% -w 1000> nul
```

You can then include calls to wait.bat in your own batch file, passing in the number of seconds to sleep.

[Apparently the Windows 2003 Resource Kit provides a Unix-like sleep command](http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html) (at last!). In the meantime, for those of us still using Windows XP, Windows 2000 or (sadly) [Windows NT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT), is there a better way?

I modified the `sleep.py` script in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-dos-batch-file#166290), so that it defaults to one second if no arguments are passed on the command line:

```py
import time, sys

time.sleep(float(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 1)
```

Comment: The Microsoft [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&DisplayLang=en) of the Windows 2003 Resource Kit indicates that it also works for XP.
I'm afraid there is no other choice but to use an 'external' utility to do the waiting: there is nothing like this built into the XP command processor.

Comment: The 2003 server resource kit works with Windows XP (and probably with w2k)

Comment: I faced the same problem in the past, and used ping myself (with a remark above clearly documenting that I realize this is stupid :) ).

Comment: Check: *[Implementing the WAIT Command in a Batch File](http://malektips.com/dos0017.html)* *[Batch file SLEEP Command](http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html)*

Comment: You have a couple of options - emulate a sleep with the [`ping`](http://malektips.com/dos0017.html) command, or download the windows resource kit which includes a `sleep` command. More details here: [Batch file SLEEP Command](http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html)

Comment: Here's some options for [batch file wait](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437201/how-to-wait-in-a-batch-script/5822491
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304738/wait-in-console
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908495/pausing-a-batch-file-for-amount-of-time
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-dos-batch-file

Comment: State `%1` rather than `%1%` to refer to the first command line argument...

Comment: A good summary of the various techniques to halt a batch file process: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php

Comment: [timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/timeout)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## UPDATE

The `timeout` command, available from Windows Vista and onwards should be the command used, as described in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5483958/6899) to this question.  What follows here is an *old* answer.

#### Old answer

If you have Python installed, or don't mind installing it (it has other uses too :), just create the following **sleep.py** script and add it somewhere in your PATH:

```py
import time, sys

time.sleep(float(sys.argv[1]))
```

It will allow sub-second pauses (for example, 1.5 sec, 0.1, etc.), should you have such a need. If you want to call it as `sleep` rather than `sleep.py`, then you can add the `.PY` extension to your PATHEXT environment variable. On Windows XP, you can edit it in:

My Computer → Properties (menu) → Advanced (tab) → Environment Variables (button) → System variables (frame)

Comment: why should we write a script in python when batch-scriptable solution is requested? How can path extension solve the problem that Windows users have no python interpreter installed? Thanks.

Comment: For portability sake, I think this solution should be avoided as there are perfectly fine native alternatives.

Comment: This approach might have provided a workaround in the past, but the native solution described by @Blorgbeard is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 244):

The [`timeout`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754891.aspx) command is available from Windows Vista onwards:

```
c:\> timeout /?

TIMEOUT [/T] timeout [/NOBREAK]

Description:
    This utility accepts a timeout parameter to wait for the specified
    time period (in seconds) or until any key is pressed. It also
    accepts a parameter to ignore the key press.

Parameter List:
    /T        timeout       Specifies the number of seconds to wait.
                            Valid range is -1 to 99999 seconds.

    /NOBREAK                Ignore key presses and wait specified time.

    /?                      Displays this help message.

NOTE: A timeout value of -1 means to wait indefinitely for a key press.

Examples:
    TIMEOUT /?
    TIMEOUT /T 10
    TIMEOUT /T 300 /NOBREAK
    TIMEOUT /T -1
```

Note: It does not work with input redirection - trivial example:

```
C:\>echo 1 | timeout /t 1 /nobreak
ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately.
```

Comment: does not work in console-less uses: "ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately."

Comment: I meant cases where you don't have a console at all, such as when the batch file is run in the background via a fork from some other process, a cygwin crontab, or remote ssh command, etc.

Comment: Oh yeah I know. The example i gave was just to demonstrate the error :)

Comment: The [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754891.aspx) to the documentation for `timeout`, added by @Cristian Ciupitu, is partially wrong -- Windows XP doesn't have this command.

Comment: Timeout didn't work for me without specifying the full path: c:\windows\system32\timeout

Comment: @HelloWorld that sounds like an issue with your %PATH%

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1672375/496289, `timeout` is not precise.

Answer (score 20):

Using the `ping` method as outlined is how I do it when I can't (or don't want to) add more executables or install any other software.

You should be pinging something that isn't there, and using the `-w` flag so that it fails after that amount of time, not pinging something that *is* there (like localhost) `-n` times. This allows you to handle time less than a second, and I think it's slightly more accurate.

e.g.

(test that 1.1.1.1 isn't taken)

```
ECHO Waiting 15 seconds

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 15000 > NUL
  or
PING -n 15 -w 1000 127.1 >NUL
```

Comment: Instantly returns with `PING: transmit failed. General failure.`

Comment: IP `1.1.1.1` is taken by CloudFlare, so this will not wait 15s but around some ms.

Comment: ...and that is why you don't pick some "surely not taken" IP address x)

Answer (score 16):

`SLEEP.exe` is included in most Resource Kits e.g. [The Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) which can be installed on Windows XP too.

```
Usage:  sleep      time-to-sleep-in-seconds
        sleep [-m] time-to-sleep-in-milliseconds
        sleep [-c] commited-memory ratio (1%-100%)
```

Answer (score 15):

I disagree with the answers I found here.

I use the following method entirely based on Windows XP capabilities to do a delay in a batch file:

DELAY.BAT:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM DELAY seconds

REM GET ENDING SECOND
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=:." %%A IN ("%TIME%") DO SET /A H=%%A, M=1%%B%%100, S=1%%C%%100, ENDING=(H*60+M)*60+S+%1

REM WAIT FOR SUCH A SECOND
:WAIT
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=:." %%A IN ("%TIME%") DO SET /A H=%%A, M=1%%B%%100, S=1%%C%%100, CURRENT=(H*60+M)*60+S
IF %CURRENT% LSS %ENDING% GOTO WAIT
```

You may also insert the day in the calculation so the method also works when the delay interval pass over midnight.

Comment: This should be accurate, but it is a CPU intensive way to go about it. Normally you want an interupt driven implementation so that the process does not consume CPU cycles while it waits. This shouldn't be a problem for infrequent short waits, as is probably the case for most batch situations. But a continuously running process with long waits could have a negative impact on system performance.

Comment: As it uses the system clock the accuracy is one second. If 2 seconds is specified, the delay can be anything between 2 seconds and 3 seconds (actually 2.99999... seconds).

Comment: What if the time is now 7:59:59 and you want to wait 7 seconds? This looks like it doesn't take that into account.

Comment: This consumes more CPU time than it counts system time. In addition you are doing arithmetic operations with octal numbers, since minutes and seconds smaller than 10 are displayed with a leading 0 in the `TIME` command.

Comment: @mrt: If you review my solution, you'll realize that it correctly manage minutes and seconds with a leading zero...

Comment: Yes I noticed the modulo operation, yet the script always gives me this error various times: `Illegal number. Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11) or octal (021) numbers`.

Comment: @mrt, @dbenham The issue of this method consuming 100% of CPU time can be mitigated by inserting a delay of say, 500 mS using the `ping` method immediately after the `WAIT:` label, e.g. `PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 500 > NUL`.  This change will mean that the batch file spends the vast majority of it's time inside the ping timeout, which presumably doesn't consume significant CPU cycles.

Comment: The `illegal number` script error is because in a `set` command, batch assumes any numeric literal starting with `0` is _octal_, so `08` and `09` trip it up.  I just add a couple of check statements, so if I want to get the number of seconds from the current time: `set Secs=%time:~6,2%`, `if %Secs%==08 set Secs=8`, `if %Secs%==09 set Secs=9`.

Comment: @rossmcm: If you review the code, the seconds are taken this way: `SET /A S=1%%C%%100`. If the seconds are `08`, previous SET command is executed this way: `SET /A S = 108 % 100` that set S = 8; this means that `Illegal number` error _never_ happen here. Did you tested it?

Comment: @Aacini I tested your script and it always returns an error: `C:\Temp>delay.bat 5
Ungültige Zahl. Numerische Konstanten sind entweder dezimale (17),
hexadezimale (0x11) oder oktale (021) Zahlen.` The error message says that a number is invalid. The delay seems to work, though.

Comment: @mrt: This is strange. Could you remove the `@ECHO OFF` line, run the code with 1 second and post the FOR and SET lines that issue the error, please? For example: `FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=:." %A IN (" 6:56:34.14") DO SET /A H=%A, M=1%B%100,S=1%C%100, CURRENT=(H*60+M)*60+S` and `SET /A H= 6, M=156%100, S=134%100, CURRENT=(H*60+M)*60+S`.

Comment: @rossmcm: Could you confirm if you get `illegal number` error from this Batch file and post the same data I requested in previous comment, please? TIA

Comment: @Aacini Uh that's strange! When removing `@echo off`, no error message is printed. Here's the output: http://pasted.co/757bf8f7

Comment: @mrt: The problem is that your `%TIME%` use a comma to separate the centiseconds, instead of a point! Just add a comma in `DELIMS=:.,"`...

Answer (score 13):

I faced a similar problem, but I just knocked up a very short C++ console application to do the same thing. Just run *MySleep.exe 1000* - perhaps easier than downloading/installing the whole resource kit.

```c
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Windows.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Sleeping for %s ms\n"), argv[1]);
        Sleep(_tstoi(argv[1]));
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Wrong number of arguments.\n"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use ping:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11 -w 1000 >nul: 2>nul:
```

It will wait 10 seconds.

The reason you have to use 11 is because the first ping goes out immediately, not after one second. The number should always be one more than the number of seconds you want to wait.

Keep in mind that the purpose of the `-w` is not to control how often packets are sent, it's to ensure that you wait no *more* than some time in the event that there are network problems. There are unlikely to be problems if you're pinging 127.0.0.1 so this is probably moot.

The `ping` command on its own will normally send one packet per second. This is not actually documented in the Windows docs but it appears to follow the same rules as the Linux version (where it is documented).

Comment: it is not recommended to use this for critical real-time processing.
because PING command is being used, it is possible that this WAIT batch file may run over a few milliseconds

Comment: @Wael, if you're talking about waiting on one-second boundaries, a few milliseconds will be irrelevant. And if you're using cmd.exe for realtime stuff, you deserve everything you get :-)

Comment: -w is a timeout value. It's the number of milliseconds to wait for a reply ... *not* the amount of time to wait *between* pings.

Comment: @quux, nowhere did I state `-w` was the timeout (though I admit some may infer that due to my lack of clarity), it's actually used to limit the cycle time where there are network problems which would cause each cycle to take _more_ than its allocated second. I've added a paragraph to the end to clarify this.

Comment: issue is that if pings return *faster*, you may not wait one full second between pings. so your wait loop will end faster than you thought it would

Comment: @quux, ping itself has an interval of one second. The fact tha ICMP replies come back in milliseconds doesn't change this. You can change the interval (at least on Linux) but the default is one second. Hence your concern re fast replies is unfounded.

Comment: Sorry for bumping an old answer: Although timing tests corroborate that the ping interval is indeed (close to) 1 second, I was wondering if you know a reference for this? Could not find it in the [ping docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping).

Comment: @djvg, you're correct, it's not in the docs. Just based on observation.

Answer (score 10):

Over at Server Fault, [a similar question was asked](https://serverfault.com/questions/38318/better-way-to-wait-a-few-seconds-in-a-bat-file), and the solution there was:

```
choice /d y /t 5 > nul
```

Comment: FYI: Choice is not included in Windows XP. It was in Windows 9x, removed from XP, and added back for Vista onward.

Comment: I do not recommended this at all. At least in all the `CHOICE` versions I know, if someone hits a button while waiting, which impatient folks do sometimes, then choice will register an input, give a system beep for a bad input, and halt the countdown timer, which means it will hang there unless they push N or Y. And if they just happen to push one of those two, then the choice ends right there instead of waiting for 5. Also, this choice is using really weird Vista syntax. All the normal choice commands would instead use `CHOICE /T:Y,5 > NUL` for that. There is no `/D` flag in the old versions.

Comment: To top it off, at least the CHOICE commands I know have different default yes/no buttons based on the language it came in, so if you happen to rely on a default [Y,N] choice instead of explicitly specifying it with `/C:YN` or just `/C:Y`, this is not going to work when someone happens to have, say, a Swedish choice command which will probably do a [J,N] by default. So this is mired in all sorts of trouble.

Comment: @Coding Tested this in Win7, and if the user presses a button, it will beep, however it will still timeout after an additional 5 seconds after the user pressed a button.  So if the user keeps pressing keys, it will never timeout.

Also, in my case, when I used this, I believe that hide the console, so that the user couldn't press the button.  On this system, there was no access to Python, there was no access to drop my own exe on the system (as suggested in some other answers), I was pretty limited in what I could do.

So, What would you recommend?

Comment: @mlsteeves Every different Windows, DOS, etc. has a different choice command and as noted it is not normally available in Xp. Many choice commands have subtly different behavior and some even have different syntax. Me, I generally use the ping command when I need a sleep. It's ugly, but reliable.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the Windows *cscript WSH* layer and this *wait.js* JavaScript file:

```
if (WScript.Arguments.Count() == 1)
    WScript.Sleep(WScript.Arguments(0)*1000);
else
    WScript.Echo("Usage: cscript wait.js seconds");
```

Comment: The Windows Scripting Host can be disabled via group policies, though.

Answer (score 9):

There is a better way to sleep using ping. You'll want to ping an address that does not exist, so you can specify a timeout with millisecond precision. Luckily, such an address is defined in a standard (RFC 3330), and it is `192.0.2.x`. This is not made-up, it really is an address with the sole purpose of not-existing. To be clear, this applies even in local networks.

> 192.0.2.0/24 - This block is assigned as "TEST-NET" for use in
> documentation and example code.  It is often used in conjunction with
> domain names example.com or example.net in vendor and protocol
> documentation.  Addresses within this block should not appear on the
> public Internet.

To sleep for 123 milliseconds, use **`ping 192.0.2.1 -n 1 -w 123 >nul`**

Update: As per the comments, there is also `127.255.255.255`.

Comment: Yes, this is easier to write and understand than having to ***add one*** to the `-n` parameter.

Comment: However, I have measured it (using 100 pings). If I use -n 3 -w 124, the actual time is exactly (3+1)*(124+1) = 4*125 = 500 ms. The timing is surprisingly stable, exact to the 10 ms resolution in the readout (by a CMD prompt with time) - and the underlying resolution is definitely better than 10 ms (not affected by the usual 16 ms tick resolution).

Comment: @mafu That 192.0.2.0/24 should not be used does not mean it cannot be used and therefore it is not really guaranteed that there is no reply on the echo request(s). For example configure for any Windows PC the static IPv4 address 192.0.2.1 and the subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and connect the network adapter to any other device. A simple switch is enough on which nothing else is connected. Then run `ping 192.0.2.1` on this Windows PC and it can be seen that Windows TCP/IP stack replies on the echo requests. How many people know that 192.0.2.0/24 should not be used for a static IPv4 address?

Comment: Per the discussion in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56863626/1945651), it seems that 192.0.2.1 is not all that foolproof and some are suggesting that 127.255.255.255 is a better choice. Thoughts?

Comment: The comments mentioned in the post above have now been removed (probably as NLN), but I would agree with the change to `127.255.255.255` due to it being a broadcast loopback address in Windows which is already assigned to by default (You can confirm this by running `route print` in cmd and looking through the IPv4 route table it prints).

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your compatibility needs, either use `ping`:

```
ping -n <numberofseconds+1> localhost >nul 2>&1
```

e.g. to wait 5 seconds, use

```
ping -n 6 localhost >nul 2>&1
```

or on Windows 7 or later use `timeout`:

```
timeout 6 >nul
```

Comment: `-w` is in milliseconds, `-n` is just the number of times to ping and the default time between pings is a second.

Answer (score 8):

If you've got [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) on your system, you can just execute this command:

```
powershell -command "Start-Sleep -s 1"
```

---

Edit: from [my answer on a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16803409/114200), people raised an issue where the amount of time powershell takes to start is significant compared to how long you're trying to wait for. If the accuracy of the wait time is important (ie a second or two extra delay is not acceptable), you can use this approach:

```
powershell -command "$sleepUntil = [DateTime]::Parse('%date% %time%').AddSeconds(5); $sleepDuration = $sleepUntil.Subtract((get-date)).TotalMilliseconds; start-sleep -m $sleepDuration"
```

This takes the time when the windows command was issued, and the powershell script sleeps until 5 seconds after that time. So as long as powershell takes less time to start than your sleep duration, this approach will work (it's around 600ms on my machine).

Comment: If you add powershell argument `-noprofile` your powershell will start decently fast no matter how much extra you've added to your user profile.

Comment: This method seems to be the simplest to use if you need to sleep for arbitrary fraction of a second. Parameter `-Milliseconds` can be used for that.

Answer (score 8):

```
timeout /t <seconds> <options>
```

For example, to make the script perform a non-uninterruptible 2-second wait:

```
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
```

Which means the script will wait 2 seconds before continuing.

By default, a keystroke will interrupt the timeout, so use the `/nobreak` switch if you don't want the user to be able to interrupt (cancel) the wait. Furthermore, the timeout will provide per-second notifications to notify the user how long is left to wait; this can be removed by piping the command to `NUL`.

**edit:** As [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) [points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-batch-file#comment37041186_24022832), the `timeout` command is only available on Windows 7 and above. Furthermore, the `ping` command uses less processor time than `timeout`. I still believe in using `timeout` where possible, though, as it is more readable than the `ping` 'hack'. Read more [here](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html).

Comment: [Apparently](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) this command is only available in Windows 7/2008 and the XP Resource Kit (and possibly 8/8.1). The source also claims the `ping` approach uses less processor time.

Answer (score 5):

Just put this in your batch file where you want the wait.

```
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11 -w 1000 > null
```

Comment: How is this different from paxdiablo's answer?

Comment: It is not different, but the answers in here are from multiple merged questions, so not all answers existed when I replied.

Answer (score 4):

The [Resource Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Kit) has always included this. At least since Windows 2000.

Also, the Cygwin package has a `sleep` - plop that into your PATH and include the `cygwin.dll` (or whatever it's called) and way to go!

Comment: Note that cygwin1.dll does not peacefully coexist with different versions of itself. You better have one and only one cygwin1.dll on your machine, or you will get weird failures.

Comment: Which Resource Kit? There seems to be more than one. Can you update your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Even more lightweight than the Python solution is a Perl
one-liner.

To sleep for seven seconds put this in the BAT script:

```
perl -e "sleep 7"
```

This solution only provides a resolution of one second.

If you need higher resolution then use the Time::HiRes
module from CPAN. It provides `usleep()` which sleeps in
microseconds and `nanosleep()` which sleeps in nanoseconds
(both functions takes only integer arguments). See the
Stack Overflow question *[How do I sleep for a millisecond in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896904)* for further details.

I have used [ActivePerl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) for many years. It is very easy to
install.

Comment: ActivePerl seems to require an account and furthermore "Get Started" page "is configured to block access from your country". [Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/) may be an easier choice

Comment: `Time::HiRes` has been in core since perl v5.7.3 - see `corelist -a Time::HiRes` or [online](https://perldoc.perl.org/modules) - so no need for [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/). Oneliner for half-second sleep: `perl -MTime::HiRes=sleep -e 'sleep 0.5'`

Answer (score 4):

In Notepad, write:

```
@echo off
set /a WAITTIME=%1+1
PING 127.0.0.1 -n %WAITTIME% > nul
goto:eof
```

Now save as wait.bat in the folder C:\WINDOWS\System32,
then whenever you want to wait, use:

```
CALL WAIT.bat <whole number of seconds without quotes>
```

Comment: It pings itself repeatedly, waiting a second between each ping, and then it returns to the calling program, i don't see the infinite loop, but i have tested it myself.

Comment: My mistake, there's no infinite loop. However, as mentioned in one of the [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6852798/355230), it's better to `ping` something not just once, and use the `-w Timeout` option for the delay-time in milliseconds rather than the `-n Count` whole number-of-retries option.

Comment: `-w Timeout` may be better, but i made sure it pings one more time than the time entered.

Answer (score 3):

The usage of [ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) is good, as long as you just want to "wait for a bit". This since you are dependent on other functions underneath, like your network working and the fact that there is nothing answering on 127.0.0.1. ;-)  Maybe it is not very likely it fails, but it is not impossible...

If you want to be sure that you are waiting exactly the specified time, you should use the `sleep` functionality (which also have the advantage that it doesn't use CPU power or wait for a network to become ready).

To find an already made executable for sleep is the most convenient way. Just drop it into your Windows folder or any other part of your standard path and it is always available.

Otherwise, if you have a compiling environment you can easily make one yourself.
The `Sleep` function is available in `kernel32.dll`, so you just need to use that one. :-)
For VB / VBA declare the following in the beginning of your source to declare a sleep function:

```
private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (byval dwMilliseconds as Long)
```

For C#:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void Sleep(uint dwMilliseconds);
```

You'll find here more about this functionality (available since Windows 2000) in *[Sleep function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28VS.85%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

In standard C, `sleep()` is included in the standard library and in Microsoft's Visual Studio C the function is named `Sleep()`, if memory serves me. ;-) Those two takes the argument in seconds, not in milliseconds as the two previous declarations.

Comment: Sleep is available in the .net framework - have a look at the thread class, e.g.:

using System.Threading;
....
Thread.Sleep(1000);

Comment: If "ping 127.0.0.1" fails, you have more serious stuff than "sleep" to worry about - this is the loopback interface, anything RPC will probably go mad.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using this C# sleep program. It might be more convenient for you if C# is your preferred language:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace sleep
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 1)
            {
                double time = Double.Parse(args[0]);
                Thread.Sleep((int)(time*1000));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: sleep <seconds>\nExample: sleep 10");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I like [Aacini's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6806192/2020158).  I added to it to handle the day and also enable it to handle [centiseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centisecond) (`%TIME%` outputs `H:MM:SS.CC`):

```
:delay
SET DELAYINPUT=%1
SET /A DAYS=DELAYINPUT/8640000
SET /A DELAYINPUT=DELAYINPUT-(DAYS*864000)

::Get ending centisecond (10 milliseconds)
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%A IN ("%TIME%") DO SET /A H=%%A, M=1%%B%%100, S=1%%C%%100, X=1%%D%%100, ENDING=((H*60+M)*60+S)*100+X+DELAYINPUT
SET /A DAYS=DAYS+ENDING/8640000
SET /A ENDING=ENDING-(DAYS*864000)

::Wait for such a centisecond
:delay_wait
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%A IN ("%TIME%") DO SET /A H=%%A, M=1%%B%%100, S=1%%C%%100, X=1%%D%%100, CURRENT=((H*60+M)*60+S)*100+X
IF DEFINED LASTCURRENT IF %CURRENT% LSS %LASTCURRENT% SET /A DAYS=DAYS-1
SET LASTCURRENT=%CURRENT%
IF %CURRENT% LSS %ENDING% GOTO delay_wait
IF %DAYS% GTR 0 GOTO delay_wait
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Or command line Python, for example, for 6 and a half seconds:

```
python -c "import time;time.sleep(6.5)"
```

Comment: Although shorter, this is a duplicate of the accepted answer.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: It also allows you to easily put everything into a single line of a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution that should work on all Windows versions after Windows 2000 would be:

```
timeout numbersofseconds /nobreak > nul
```

Comment: Doesn't work on XP Pro...`'timeout' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to accomplish a '*sleep*' in cmd/batch:

My favourite one:

```
TIMEOUT /NOBREAK 5 >NUL 2>NUL
```

This will stop the console for 5 seconds, without any output.

Most used:

```
ping localhost -n 5 >NUL 2>NUL
```

This will try to make a connection to `localhost` 5 times. Since it is hosted on your computer, it will always reach the host, so every second it will try the new every second. The `-n` flag indicates how many times the script will try the connection. In this case is 5, so it will last 5 seconds.

Variants of the last one:

```
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 5 >nul
```

In this script there are some differences comparing it with the last one. This will not try to call `localhost`. Instead, it will try to connect to `1.1.1.1`, a very fast website. The action will last 5 seconds **only if you have an active internet connection. Else it will last approximately 15 to complete the action**. I do not recommend using this method.

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 >nul
```

This is exactly the same as example 2 (most used). Also, you can also use:

```
ping [::1] -n 5 >nul
```

This instead, uses IPv6's `localhost` version.

There are lots of methods to perform this action. However, I prefer method 1 for Windows Vista and later versions and the most used method (method 2) for earlier versions of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I am impressed with this one:

http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm#02

```
choice /n /c y /d y /t 5 > NUL
```

Technically, you're telling the `choice` command to accept only y. It defaults to y, to do so in 5 seconds, to draw no prompt, and to dump anything it does say to NUL (like null terminal on Linux).

Comment: I'll echo myself here: I do not recommended this at all. In the `CHOICE` versions I know, if someone hits a key while waiting, which impatient folks do sometimes, then choice will read an input, give a system beep for a bad input, and halt the countdown, so it will hang unless they push Y. And if they just happen to push Y, then the choice ends right there instead of waiting for 5. Also, this choice is using really weird Vista syntax. The normal choice commands  instead use `CHOICE /T:Y,5 > NUL` for that. (There is no /D flag in the old versions.) And if you have Vista, use `TIMEOUT` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a .vbs file to do specific timeouts:

The code below creates the .vbs file. Put this near the top of you rbatch code:

```
echo WScript.sleep WScript.Arguments(0) >"%cd%\sleeper.vbs"
```

The code below then opens the .vbs and specifies how long to wait for:

```
start /WAIT "" "%cd%\sleeper.vbs" "1000"
```

In the above code, the "1000" is the value of time delay to be sent to the .vbs file in milliseconds, for example, 1000 ms = 1 s. You can alter this part to be however long you want.

The code below deletes the .vbs file after you are done with it. Put this at the end of your batch file:

```
del /f /q "%cd%\sleeper.vbs"
```

And here is the code all together so it's easy to copy:

```
echo WScript.sleep WScript.Arguments(0) >"%cd%\sleeper.vbs"
start /WAIT "" "%cd%\sleeper.vbs" "1000"
del /f /q "%cd%\sleeper.vbs"
```

Answer (score 1):

The pathping.exe can sleep less than second.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
echo !TIME! & pathping localhost -n -q 1 -p %~1 2>&1 > nul & echo !TIME!
```

.

```
> sleep 10
17:01:33,57
17:01:33,60

> sleep 20
17:03:56,54
17:03:56,58

> sleep 50
17:04:30,80
17:04:30,87

> sleep 100
17:07:06,12
17:07:06,25

> sleep 200
17:07:08,42
17:07:08,64

> sleep 500
17:07:11,05
17:07:11,57

> sleep 800
17:07:18,98
17:07:19,81

> sleep 1000
17:07:22,61
17:07:23,62

> sleep 1500
17:07:27,55
17:07:29,06
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, if you have Node.js installed, you can use

```
node -e 'setTimeout(a => a, 5000)'
```

to sleep for 5 seconds. It works on a Mac with Node v12.14.0.

Comment: And here's a version using `await`: `node --input-type=module -e "await new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, 5000))"` (yes, the OP's is better, haha)

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers on this issue noting the use of ping, but most of them point to loopback addresses or addresses that are now seen as valid addresses for DNS.

Instead of that, you should use a TEST-NET IP address reserved for documentation use only, per the IETF.
([more information on that here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses))

Here is a fully commented batch script to demonstrate the use of a sleep function using ping:

```
@echo off
:: turns off command-echoing

echo/Script will now wait for 2.5 seconds & echo/
:: prints a line followed by a linebreak

call:sleep 2500
:: waits for two-and-a-half seconds (2500 milliseconds)

echo/Done! Press any key to continue ... & pause >NUL
:: prints a line and pauses

goto:EOF
:: prevents the batch file from executing functions beyond this point


::--FUNCTIONS--::

:SLEEP
:: call this function with the time to wait (in milliseconds)

ping 203.0.113.0 -n 1 -w "%~1" >NUL
:: 203.0.113.0 = TEST-NET-3 reserved IP; -n = ping count; -w = timeout

goto:EOF
:: ends the call subroutine
```

And of course, you can also just use the command directly if you don't want to make a function:
`ping 203.0.113.0 -n 1 -w` *timeInMilliseconds* `>NUL`

Answer (score 0):

You can get fancy by putting the PAUSE message in the title bar:

```
@ECHO off
SET TITLETEXT=Sleep
TITLE %TITLETEXT%
CALL :sleep 5
GOTO :END
:: Function Section
:sleep ARG
ECHO Pausing...
FOR /l %%a in (%~1,-1,1) DO (TITLE Script %TITLETEXT% -- time left^
 %%as&PING.exe -n 2 -w 1000 127.1>NUL)
EXIT /B 0
:: End of script
:END
pause
::this is EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

From Windows Vista on you have the [TIMEOUT](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) and [SLEEP](http://ss64.com/nt/sleep.html) commands, but to use them on Windows XP or Windows Server 2003, you'll need the [Windows Server 2003 resource tool kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657).

[Here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php) you have a good overview of sleep alternatives (the ping approach is the most popular as it will work on every Windows machine), but there's (at least) one not mentioned which (ab)uses the [`W32TM`](https://ss64.com/nt/w32tm.html) (Time Service) command:

```
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:N  >nul 2>&1
```

Where you should replace the N with the seconds you want to pause. Also, it will work on every Windows system without prerequisites.

Typeperf can also be used:

```
typeperf "\System\Processor Queue Length" -si N -sc 1 >nul
```

With mshta and javascript (can be used for sleep under a second):

```
start "" /wait /min /realtime mshta "javascript:setTimeout(function(){close();},5000)"
```

This should be even more precise (for waiting under a second) - self compiling executable relying on `.net`:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off
setlocal
::del %~n0.exe /q /f
::
:: For precision better call this like
:: call waitMS 500
:: in order to skip compilation in case there's already built .exe
:: as without pointed extension first the .exe will be called due to the ordering in PATEXT variable
::
::
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:-d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*jsc.exe"') do (
   set "jsc=%%v"
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
    "%jsc%" /nologo /w:0 /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
)


%~n0.exe %*

endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%


*/


import System;
import System.Threading;

var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
function printHelp(){
    Console.WriteLine(arguments[0]+" N");
    Console.WriteLine(" N - milliseconds to wait");
    Environment.Exit(0);    
}

if(arguments.length<2){
    printHelp();
}

try{
    var wait:Int32=Int32.Parse(arguments[1]);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(wait);
}catch(err){
    Console.WriteLine('Invalid Number passed');
    Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was tested on Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7 and uses CScript. I put in some safe guards to avoid del "" prompting. (`/q` would be dangerous)

Wait one second:

> sleepOrDelayExecution 1000

Wait 500 ms and then run stuff after:

```
sleepOrDelayExecution 500 dir \ /s
```

#### sleepOrDelayExecution.bat:

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "" goto end
if NOT %1 GTR 0 goto end
setlocal
set sleepfn="%temp%\sleep%random%.vbs"
echo WScript.Sleep(%1) >%sleepfn%
if NOT %sleepfn% == "" if NOT EXIST %sleepfn% goto end
cscript %sleepfn% >nul
if NOT %sleepfn% == "" if EXIST %sleepfn% del %sleepfn%
for /f "usebackq tokens=1*" %%i in (`echo %*`) DO @ set params=%%j
%params%
:end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since others are suggesting 3rd party programs (Python, Perl, custom app, etc), another option is GNU CoreUtils for Windows available at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm.

2 options for deployment:

1. Install full package (which will include the full suite of CoreUtils, dependencies, documentation, etc).
2. Install only the 'sleep.exe' binary and necessary dependencies (use depends.exe to get dependencies).

One benefit of deploying CoreUtils is that you'll additionally get a host of other programs that are helpful for scripting (Windows batch leaves a lot to be desired).

Answer (score 0):

use `timeout`

e.g.- `timeout 10` will await for 10 seconds before executing next command in `cmd` or `powershell`

Comment: It's the same answer, but with less details, as the [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5483958/463115) from Blorgbeard and that answer is over ten years old

Answer (score -2):

```
ping -n X 127.0.0.1 > nul
```

Replace X with the number of seconds + 1.

For example, if you were to wait 10 seconds, replace X with 11. To wait 5 seconds, use 6.

Read earlier answers for milliseconds.