# How to wait in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script and trying to wait 10 seconds between 2 function calls. The command:

```
sleep 10
```

Does not make the batch file wait for 10 seconds.

I am running Windows XP.

**Note:** This is not a complete duplicate of [Sleeping in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044) as the other question is about also about python, while this is about windows batch files.

Comment: Related post - [Windows batch: sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4317020/465053)

Comment: Also see [timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/timeout)

Answer (score 288, accepted):

You can ping an address that doesn't exist and specify the desired timeout:

```
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul
```

And since the address does not exist, it'll wait 10,000 ms (10 seconds) and return.

- The `-w 10000` part specifies the desired timeout in milliseconds.
- The `-n 1` part tells ping that it should only try *once* (normally it'd try 4 times).
- The `> nul` part is appended so the ping command doesn't output anything to screen.

You can easily make a sleep command yourself by creating a sleep.bat somewhere in your PATH and using the above technique:

```
rem SLEEP.BAT - sleeps by the supplied number of seconds

@ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w %1000 > nul
```

---

**NOTE (September 2020):** The 192.0.2.x address is reserved as per [RFC 3330](http://smakd.potaroo.net/ietf/idref/rfc3330/) so it definitely will not exist in the real world. Quoting from the spec:

> 192.0.2.0/24 - This block is assigned as "TEST-NET" for use in
> documentation and example code.  It is often used in conjunction with
> domain names example.com or example.net in vendor and protocol
> documentation.  Addresses within this block should not appear on the
> public Internet.

Comment: ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul hat to do it like this since the other would finish right away.

Comment: @Thomaschaaf interesting... pinging a local machine address should've caused ping to return *right away* since it's pinging the same machine (i.e. time<1ms) so the timeout trick shouldn't have worked in that case!

Comment: I added the actual function its called timeout.. http://www.ss64.com/nt/timeout.html at least I know that others didn't know either :)

Comment: Brilliant! Although I would have preferred Windows to supply a default command!

Comment: How about `choice /c:Z /d:Z /t %seconds% > nul`?

Comment: winxp pro: 'choice' is not recognized as an operable program or batch file.

Comment: doesn't work, `ping` responds with: `PING: transmit failed. General failure.` probably because I'm in a 10.x.x.x range.

Comment: I was happily using `ping 0.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul` until Windows 10 which will immediately return with this particular IP, without any waiting. `@ping 1.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul` works.

Answer (score 151):

You'd better ping *127.0.0.1*. Windows ping pauses for one second between pings so you if you want to sleep for 10 seconds, use

```
ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 > nul
```

This way you don't need to worry about unexpected early returns (say, there's no default route and the 123.45.67.89 is instantly known to be unreachable.)

Comment: I like this solution more than the the one marked as the answer because this is cleaner as we don't have to make sure that our script has a non-existent IP address. Therefore, we can write the script once and use it on any Windows system in any network without editing the script again.

Comment: Since [RFC 3330](http://smakd.potaroo.net/ietf/idref/rfc3330/) became obsoleted I'm using this solution.

Comment: Or perhaps use localhost to avoid problems on IPv6-only machines.

Answer (score 139):

I actually found the right command to use.. its called timeout: http://www.ss64.com/nt/timeout.html

Comment: alternative would be chakrits http://www.ss64.com/nt/sleep.html

Comment: Also not a Windows XP command...

Comment: Now that WindowsXP is on the way out, it seems like this is really the way to do it in the future.

Comment: This may not have been the correct answer for XP in 2009 but it is for Windows 7 and above!

Comment: In 2016, this should become the correct answer.

Comment: As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1672375/508654, "timeout 5" actually sleeps anywhere between 4 and 5 seconds. So "timeout 1" might be done in a half of a second, 10 milliseconds, etc. Timeout just sleeps until the next full second comes.

Answer (score 49):

I used this

```
:top
cls
type G:\empty.txt
type I:\empty.txt
timeout /T 500
goto top
```

Comment: timeout is nice solution. Its in fact better than sleep. It tells time remaining!

Comment: `timeout` command isn't available on Windows XP. It works on Windows 2003 and Windows 7 though.

Comment: seconds? milliseconds? minutes? what is the unit that it uses?

Comment: @ItayLevin: the unit is seconds.

Answer (score 7):

What about:

```
@echo off
set wait=%1
echo waiting %wait% s
echo wscript.sleep %wait%000 > wait.vbs
wscript.exe wait.vbs
del wait.vbs
```

Comment: This is the only solution that seems to be accurate even for delays that are `<1000ms`.

Answer (score 6):

Well, does `sleep` even exist on your Windows XP box? According to this post: http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html `sleep` isn't available on Windows XP, and you have to download the [Windows 2003 Resource Kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Kit#Windows_Resource_Kits) in order to get it.

Chakrit's answer gives you another way to pause, too.

Try running `sleep 10` from a command prompt.