# Is it possible to issue a wait command in a batch file?

Tags: c#, iis-7, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that runs several .cmd files.  I would like to know if it is possible to have it wait 60 seconds or so before running the last one.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait in a batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735285/how-to-wait-in-a-batch-script)

Comment: ^ Possible Duplicate of someone who has too much time on their hands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search came up with this answer...

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 30000 >NUL

It'll try and ping until the timeout (30000ms)

Comment: that is the most roundabout way to induce a timeout.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm not a batch script expert, i just read this..."i am told that windows .bat files do not have a sleep or wait command" on a blog. It appears that TIMEOUT is a windows 7 command.

Comment: Reading the other answers futher it appears that they require a download which might not be available if its a hosted server. Would you mind un-downvoting my answer please? it achieves the result regardless of if you think it's your favourite method.

Comment: i personally thought this was a great answer, it solved my problem for the OS that i am using w/o having to download any resource kits

Comment: out of curiosity, will this work if the machine has no network card?

Comment: Dunno, whip your card out and try it.

Comment: Upvoted: if the OP is happy with the answer over all the others then I fail to see how it can be -1.

Comment: The IP `1.1.1.1` is now taken by CloudFlare, so this will not wait for 30s but return in some ms.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `timeout [seconds]` i.e. `timeout 60`

Comment: it just keeps saying timeout not recognized timeout /t 40

Comment: What OS are you using? This works fine out of the box on Win 7 - you might have to download the resource kit as suggested in other posts for older OS's

Comment: Yep you will need to download the resource kit for this to work, then you can use either Sleep or Timeout.

Answer (score 4):

Another "workaround" is by using the `choice` command which is better supported on the various windows/dos OS-es:

```
choice /c a /t 10 /d a > nul
```

will cause a pause of 10 seconds while nothing will be seen on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

use the "Sleep" command.   You need to download it (part of the Windows resource kits)
[More information here on sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/48231/windows-7-bat-file-wait-sleep)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)

```
Syntax
  TIMEOUT [seconds]
```

or [Sleep](http://ss64.com/nt/sleep.html) from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en)

```
Syntax
  SLEEP [seconds]
```

Answer (score 1):

`PING 127.0.0.1 -n 61`

What this does is ping the computer itself, it will always reply instantly, and the time between pings is 1 second, and the first ping goes instantly, so just add how many seconds you want + 1 as the number of pings to send. In this case, it will wait 60 seconds.

Comment: This will work for all versions of windows, some older ones (eg xp) dont have certain timeout/sleep procedures

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a pure cmd script, use the following pieces of code.

First, this snippet returns the current time in hundreths of seconds.

```
:gettime
set hh=%time:~0,2%
set mm=%time:~3,2%
set ss=%time:~6,2%
set cc=%time:~-2%
set /A %1=hh*360000+mm*6000+ss*100+cc
goto :eof
```

You may then use it to build a wait loop like this.

```
:wait
call :gettime wait0
:w2
call :gettime wait1
set /A waitt = wait1-wait0
if !waitt! lss %1 goto :w2
goto :eof
```

and, finally, putting all pieces together, you have this example of usage

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

call :gettime t1
echo %t1%
call :wait %1
call :gettime t2
echo %t2%
set /A tt = (t2-t1)/100
echo %tt%
goto :eof

:wait
call :gettime wait0
:w2
call :gettime wait1
set /A waitt = wait1-wait0
if !waitt! lss %1 goto :w2
goto :eof

:gettime 
set hh=%time:~0,2%
set mm=%time:~3,2%
set ss=%time:~6,2%
set cc=%time:~-2%
set /A %1=hh*360000+mm*6000+ss*100+cc
goto :eof
```

For a more detailed description of the commands used here, check `HELP SET` and `HELP CALL` information.

Answer (score 0):

GREAT! So THIS one is the correct solution, finnaly.
Just a detail, if You use it at the localised OS, make sure Your "DELIMS" setting fits.
For example, use "DELIMS=:," instead of "DELIMS=:." for Czech localisation.