# Delay command in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, cmd

In the Linux prompt, I can run `sleep 5 && echo hello &` to delay a command to get executed after 5 seconds but **how can I do this in Windows 7s' command prompt?**

To explain further what I'm trying to do: In the end I need to execute a python script, such as the one below but in Windows 7. The python script needs to finish and exit. Then after a while I want the Windows machine to execute the command.

```
import subprocess
command = 'sleep 5 && echo hello'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: This is a very nice trick / hack at http://stackoverflow.com/a/735294/1662973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct solution for delay on windows prompt. One solution i've used was as follow:

Create **wait.bat** file

```
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n %1% -w 1000 > nul
```

and while calling command from python use it like:

```
import subprocess
command = 'wait.bat 5 & echo hello'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect for what I needed to do!

Comment: It should read `%1` rather than `%1%` (it should refer to the 1st argument, shouldn't it?)...

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you get the `sleep` command (e.g.: `sleep 3` for 3 seconds pause). However, this command may not be installed.

An alternative is (on Windows):

```
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this from the Windows cmd shell you can just ping an invalid ip address wit ha no of ms e.g.

```
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
```

to wait one second.

Or to do this in Python you can import sleep from the Time library e.g.

```
from time import sleep
sleep(1)
```

You just put the no of seconds as the arguement.