# add delay between run 2 exe files in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to run two exe files say 1.exe and 2.exe using bat command. All I need is first run 1.exe then wait for 30 sec then run 2.exe. How to write it using batch script

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735285/how-to-wait-in-a-batch-script

Comment: Yes. The method for putting in a "wait" is exactly described in citation in above comment.

Comment: 1 and 2 specified in the question is two autoit scripts so when I run with wait between the two, overlapping occurs ie, I feel like both scripts are running simultaneously. I tried wait 30 and wait 30000.