# How do I create a batch scrolling starwars text effect?

Tags: list, batch-file, text, scroll, cmd

I want a Star Wars text effect in a batch file even if it doesn't get smaller when the text reaches the top.

How can I make text scroll up?

```
@echo off
Cls
:top
Echo %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random%
Goto top
```

Comment: well, that code **does** scroll, when the end of the screen is reached. If you think of "smooth scrolling" (pixelwise): no way to do that with batch (and I'm quite sure not possible in a cmd window at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first `cls` and then print a lot of blank lines, any new lines you print will scroll up from the bottom of the screen. Also, you can [use the ping command to add a small delay to each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735294/257418). Try something like this:

```
@echo off
cls
for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do echo.
:top
echo %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random%
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 100 >nul
goto top
```