# batch file : execute start with a delay without pausing the rest of the script

Tags: batch-file, delay, batch-processing, pause

I've made a batch file which needs to open the browser at localhost and start a java program.

Simplified this currently is :

```
start "" http://localhost
java -start_java_program
```

This works fine but the browser is now already started before java is done starting the local server. So you get a not found page.

I can't execute the `start` command after the `java` command because the java keeps executing from the .bat file.

Ideally I would like to call start with like a 5 second delay and still keep executing the script and call java. So things as sleep and timeout won't work for me since java won't start as well than.

Does anybody know a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait in a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735285/how-to-wait-in-a-batch-script)

Comment: No this is not the case since that will pause the script but than java is still not started. I'll try subbu's way :)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically [Magoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45018894/1012053), but without the extra batch file. I also add the `/B` option to the initial START command - there is no need for a second console to appear.

```
@echo off
start "" /b cmd /c "timeout /nobreak 10 >nul & start "" http://localhost"
echo java -start_java_program
```

Answer (score 2):

```
start "" delayedstart.bat 10 http://localhost
```

Where `delayedstart.bat` is

```
@echo off
setlocal
timeout /t %1 >nul
start "" %2
```

I haven't tried it, but it should work...

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "start" it would start a new command window

eg.,

```
start java -start_java_program
```

then you can wait for a desired time
eg.,

```
timeout /T 10
```

to wait for 10 seconds

then launch your browser

Comment: Or run something like `start "" /b java -start_java_program <nul`  to run java in the background, but still attached to the current console. The console will persist as long as java is running and attached to it. It shouldn't interfere with subsequent programs reading from the console since its `stdin` is redirected to `nul` (but could if it manually opens `con` or `conin$`, which you don't know until you try). It can write to the console, but that shouldn't be a problem.