# How do I sleep for a millisecond in Perl?

Tags: perl, sleep

How do I sleep for shorter than a second in Perl?

Comment: It is because I believe this title is actually more helpful. Let me try to argument this. What B.D.F. did was duplicate the question in the title which adds no expressivity. When I was searching the web for the answer I actually looked for a millisecond sleep and not for a "shorter than a second" sleep. I say this version has a better chance of being hit through different google searches than B.D.F's one. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

From the Perldoc page on [sleep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html):

> For delays of finer granularity than one second, the [Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) module (from CPAN, and starting from Perl 5.8 part of the standard distribution) provides usleep().

Actually, it provides `usleep()` (which sleeps in microseconds) and `nanosleep()` (which sleeps in nanoseconds). You may want `usleep()`, which should let you deal with easier numbers. 1 millisecond sleep (using each):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes qw(usleep nanosleep);

# 1 millisecond == 1000 microseconds
usleep(1000);
# 1 microsecond == 1000 nanoseconds
nanosleep(1000000);
```

If you don't want to (or can't) load a module to do this, you may also be able to use the built-in [`select()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) function:

```
# Sleep for 250 milliseconds
select(undef, undef, undef, 0.25);
```

Comment: Caveat: although you could nanosleep(1), many OSes have some minimum granularity; e.g. I believe it's 1 ms in Windows XP, so you'd still sleep for a whole 1000000 ns there.

Comment: The page on Time::HiRes says something like "if you need nanosleep(), you should reconsider whether or not Perl is the best tool for your job."

Comment: There is also Time::HiRes::sleep( 0.3 ) which will sleep for .3 of a second.

Answer (score 39):

Time::HiRes:

```
  use Time::HiRes;
  Time::HiRes::sleep(0.1); #.1 seconds
  Time::HiRes::usleep(1); # 1 microsecond.
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html

Answer (score 13):

From [perlfaq8](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_can_I_sleep_or_a):

---

**How can I sleep() or alarm() for under a second?**

If you want finer granularity than the 1 second that the sleep() function provides, the easiest way is to use the select() function as documented in select in perlfunc. Try the Time::HiRes and the BSD::Itimer modules (available from CPAN, and starting from Perl 5.8 Time::HiRes is part of the standard distribution).

Answer (score 7):

Use [Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html).

Answer (score 5):

A quick googling on "perl high resolution timers" gave a reference to [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-HiRes/HiRes.pm). Maybe that it what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
system "sleep 0.1";
```

does the trick.

Comment: It actually worked for me (not elegant, but for debug purposes it seems to work).

Comment: not really perl, but helpfull if you don't want to install Time::HiRes but need some sleeps smaller than 1 second but **don't forget**, that spawning a shell for this takes time itself, so you can't count on accuracy!

Comment: works on linux and many systems with modern GNU `sleep` utillity installed, but will fail on BSD, MacOS, busybox-Linux, etc.  (Actually, it may work on BSD/MacOS depending on which sleep is part of the distribution)

Answer (score 0):

For 1-liner on the CLI (for systems that don't have GNU's `sleep`:

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=usleep -e 'usleep(1000000);';
```

will sleep 1s. You can verify this by prefixing `time` to the command. So to convert from microseconds to milliseconds, multiply your expected milliseconds by 1000.

```
~ otheus$ time perl -MTime::HiRes=usleep -e 'usleep(1000000);';

real  0m1.032s
user  0m0.011s
sys   0m0.010s
~ otheus$ time perl -MTime::HiRes=usleep -e 'usleep(500000);';

real  0m0.547s
user  0m0.010s
sys   0m0.026s
```