# Wait in console

Tags: console, time-wait

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pausing a batch file for amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908495/pausing-a-batch-file-for-amount-of-time)

How I can make wait x sec in console (cmd), without "timeout" command?

Comment: Dupes:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437201/how-to-wait-in-a-batch-script/5822491
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304738/wait-in-console
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908495/pausing-a-batch-file-for-amount-of-time
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-dos-batch-file