# Pausing a batch file for amount of time

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Sleeping in a DOS batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-dos-batch-file)
>   [How to wait in a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735285/how-to-wait-in-a-batch-script)

I have a program that is kicked off with a batch file.

The first module takes 10 seconds or so to initialize, and I want a way to "sleep" for 15 seconds before the second module is called, but I don't want it to require the user to hit a key like "pause" seems to require.

So, this is what I mean:

```
echo %PATH%

pause 10

echo %PATH%
```

In this example, I want there to be 10 seconds in between the echos.  Is this possible?  I've seen some examples using "ping 1.1.1.1" but it doesn't seem to work all the time correctly.

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question. For instance, what typo.pl mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338. And there must be some that are even closer.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735285. Which itself is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044, from October 2008.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html

Comment: You can use the [timeout command](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) (not included in Win XP by default).

Answer (score 17):

```
ping -n 11 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 > nul
```

**Update**

Beginner's mistake. Ping doesn't wait 1000 ms before or after an request, but inbetween requests. So to wait 10 seconds, you'll have to do 11 pings to have 10 'gaps' of a second inbetween.

Comment: This works. Delay can be interrupted by pressing Ctrl+C.

Comment: Updated my answer to change `-n 10` to `-n 11`.

Answer (score 13):

If `choice` is available, use this:

```
choice /C X /T 10 /D X > nul
```

where `/T 10` is the number of seconds to delay.
Note the syntax can vary depending on your Windows version, so use `CHOICE /?` to be sure.

Comment: This works. Delay can be interrupted by pressing X.

Comment: choice does not exist on 2000/XP, ping is a better option. If you want to support Win95 RTM and up you need to detect which platform you are on and use ping or choice.

Comment: @Anders: Yes, that's why I said "if choice is available", thanks for adding which OS lack choice, I wasn't sure anymore. Btw, a workaround is to simply copy choice.com to the target system.

Comment: +1 Great outside-the-box solution.

Comment: sleep is available in win 10. It simply runs as:  sleep 1 (// 1 second) or sleep 1m (1 minute etc). Test if your OS has sleep command by simply run: sleep 1