# How to wait in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sleeping in a DOS batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-dos-batch-file)

I am trying to write a batch script and trying to wait 10 seconds between 2 function calls.

sleep 10

does not wait for 10 seconds.

I am running Windows XP.

Needs ReAnswered

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait in a batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/735285/113116), [Pausing a batch file for amount of time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4908495/113116), [How to sleep for 5 seconds in Windows's Command Prompt? (or DOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1672338/113116)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437201/how-to-wait-in-a-batch-script/5822491
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304738/wait-in-console
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908495/pausing-a-batch-file-for-amount-of-time
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-dos-batch-file