# Script to start traceroute if continuous ping fails, output to log

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, ping, traceroute

I want to continuously ping my home public IP address, and if the ping fails automatically do a traceroute to see where it's failing.

I've been trying to follow the comments made here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/efc97c66-60a6-4fd7-8be4-4b454d040ce5

Windows compatible would be preferable, bat or vbs would be best.

From anywhere on the internet I will lose my connection to my home network. From work I have started a ping and when it drops I've done a traceroute and it fails before it gets to my IP.

I need a log file to prove that it is not my modem, or router, or computer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
@echo off
set Address=google.com
:Loop
PING -n 5 127.0.0.1>nul
echo Pinging %Address%
%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %Address% | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "TTL=" > NUL >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :Loop
echo Trace route %Address% at %date% %time% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
tracert %Address% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
goto Loop
```

This is what I ended up going with, if anyone else ever needs this. Essentially the "Ping -n 127.0.0.1>Nul" is to add a 5 second counter so that it only pinged the destination every 5 seconds, 5 can be changed to whatever value is needed.

Windows 7 has this problem where a ping may result with something like "reply from 192.168.1.5: Destination host unreachable". So instead of erroring out it gets a reply from itself and not the error level 1. 
Instead of looking for Error Level 1 I choose to look for no result for TTL with "%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %Address% | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "TTL=" > NUL"

Anyway, I'm sure the other answers here were very similar and may have worked, so I am ranking them up, but marking this as the answer.

Thanks all!

Comment: Using pathping with -n -q 5 speeds things up and give detailed stats. Or tracert with -d option. These remove the dns resolve time (which is sort of pointless to do each time... it's always going to be the same) and gives a better chance of catching a transient failure upstream.

Comment: Surely the DNS is NOT always going to be the same each time. On one of my networks, the DNS server is usually the problem!

Comment: I want to do the same, but in lunux (ubuntu 18.04), any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the script, will see if it can catch the issues I'm having currently. I did modifiy it a bit:
@echo off
set Address=google.com
set Delay=5
echo %date% %time% Ping %Address% every %Delay% seconds >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
:Loop
PING -n %Delay% 127.0.0.1>nul
echo %date% %time% Pinging
%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %Address% | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "TTL=" > NUL >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :Loop
echo %date% %time% Trace route %Address% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
tracert %Address% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
goto Loop

Answer (score 5):

```
@echo off
set Address=www.google.com
set LogDir=C:\pingtest
md %LogDir%
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "%LogDir%"
echo PingTest script to monitor network connection.  Control-C to exit.
echo Tests connection by pinging %Address%.  Logs to %LogDir%\logfile.log.
echo %date% %time% Initial tracert (trace route) to %Address% >> %LogDir%\logfile.log
tracert %Address% >> %LogDir%\logfile.log
:Loop
REM  5 second delay
PING -n 5 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul
echo %date% %time% Pinging %Address%
echo %date% %time% Pinging %Address% >> %LogDir%\logfile.log
%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %Address% | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "TTL=" > NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :Loop
echo %date% %time% PING ERROR - Tracing route to %Address%
echo %date% %time% PING ERROR - Tracing route to %Address% >> %LogDir%\logfile.log
tracert %Address% >> %LogDir%\logfile.log
goto Loop
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make a simple batch file that tries a ping and if it fails does a tracert, eg:

```
setlocal
set host=www.bigpond.com
set logfile=nettest.log
echo %date% %time%>>%logfile%
ping %host%>>%logfile%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 tracert %host%>>%logfile
endlocal
```

There's plenty of scope for refinement here.

Then create a scheduled task that runs it every five minutes or whatever suits you.

Alternatively you could include a loop with a 'sleep' in it. There's a poor man's sleep at [Sleeping in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-dos-batch-file) that uses:

```
choice /d y /t 5 > nul
```

Comment: Ever since Windows 7 and Server 2018 we have the `timeout` command.

Comment: Thanks @MicheldeRuiter, I suspect I hadn't moved onto WIndows 7 when I wrote this. Thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 2):

```
:LOOP
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%F IN (`ping localhost -n 1 -w 1 ^| find "Request"`) DO (
  IF "%%F"=="Request" (
    tracert localhost
  )
)>>log.txt
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%G IN (`echo %time%`) DO IF %G%H GTR 1400 GOTO:EOF
GOTO LOOP
```

Basically, this states do `ping`, if it finds a line that has an instance of the word `Request` (which only appears if you can't ping the address) perform a tracert. The `-n` and `-w` switches in `PING` tell it to jump only once and timeout after 1 second of not getting a response.  This is perfectly fine if you are pinging your localhost. The second `FOR` statement is to have a stopping point.  Change the `1400` to a time you wish for the script to stop (in military time of course).

Comment: This line didn't work for me:

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%G IN (`echo %time%`) DO IF %G%H GTR 1400 GOTO:EOF

it had to be:

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%G IN (`echo %time%`) DO IF %%G%%H GTR 1400 GOTO:EOF

Answer (score 0):

I have just been looking for the same thing to investigate why a VPN keeps dropping on a wired connection, used one of the batch file suggestions above which was great.
Also found a nice little Java App which packages it for you here 
[Internet Connectivity Monitor](https://code.google.com/p/internetconnectivitymonitor/)

Simple to use and does the job :-)