# Need to run an .exe, then kill it after ~10 seconds and move to next command in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to create a batch file that runs an .exe, but kills said .exe after about 10 seconds (before it completes), then moves on to the next command in the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a strange requirement.

Comment: Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/166044/785745) may be of interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
start program.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10
taskkill /im program.exe /f
rem continue here
echo Another command!
```

Comment: What if there is many `program.exe` running? I only want to kill the one I started.