# How to Kill a Command after certain period of time in Command Prompt even if it is running state

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I am running a command in command prompt and I want to kill it after 15 minutes. I don't care if it is completed or not. I don't want to have any human interaction to kill the running command such as someone has to press CTRL+C to kill it.

Is there a way to do it.

Please note I don;t want to use any third party tools or scripts.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121424/need-to-run-an-exe-then-kill-it-after-10-seconds-and-move-to-next-command-in?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to run an .exe, then kill it after ~10 seconds and move to next command in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121424/need-to-run-an-exe-then-kill-it-after-10-seconds-and-move-to-next-command-in)

Answer (score 3):

```
start forfiles /s
timeout /t 5
Taskkill /im forfiles.exe /f
```

is one way.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like that ?

```
@echo off
Tracert www.google.com
timeout /t 900 /nobreak >NUL
Taskkill /im cmd.exe /f
```

**Edit :** based on the ***blueray's*** comment :

> how can I put this command in a single line to use in CMD?

```
Tracert www.google.com & timeout /t 900 /nobreak >NUL & Taskkill /im cmd.exe /f
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help

start your-command-here

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 120 > NUL

taskkill /im cmd.exe /f
```

**Explanation:**

*start:* this command starts executing your command

*ping:* it pings your local machine(ip : 127.0.0.1) for 120 sec and >NUL redirects the output to nowhere else the output of ping command will be displayed on the cmd screen

*taskkill:* it is used to kill any task

*/im:* image name of the process to be terminated. if the command is running on cmd then cmd.exe or any program that you need to kill.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works well for me:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo off

set _time=0
set _timeout=30

start myprocess.exe

:waitforprocess
set /A _time=_time+1
IF !_time! GTR !_timeout! goto TimedOut

rem TaskList will return the task list of the image as specific
rem or it will return INFO: No tasks are running.... so look for 
rem the INFO statement using FindStr. FindStr will return a errorlevel
rem of 0 if it found the string and a 1 if it did not, so use that 
rem to work out next steps. 
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------
tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME EQ myprocess.exe" | findstr INFO 

rem ERRORLEVEL 1 = Did not find the string, so try again. 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK > nul
    goto :waitforprocess
)
GOTO DONE

:TimedOut
ECHO We timedout so will kill the process
taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME EQ myprocess.exe" /T /F

:Done
echo finished
```