# Process waitForExit() doesn't work

Tags: c#, process, waitforexit

I have the following code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\unRAR.exe";



p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"e c:\appData.rar c:\folderek\";

p.Start();
p.WaitForExit(9000);
```

I would like the window not to close after extracting files (`unRAR.exe` extracts them). `WaitForExit(9000)` seems not to work. I read dozens of sites and still can't find any solution.

Comment: What does "seems not to work" mean? Do explain the actual issue (expected behavior, what you actually get (error...) etc.).

Comment: It doesn't wait. I want the window to remain visible and not close itself. Is there a possibility to for process to wait for a keypress?

Comment: That's not in your control. If the code in the application you execute is closing its window, there's nothing you can do to stop it. Find different utility that isn't closing its window.

Comment: @user1284257 What you described is **very** different from your question. Your code waits for the process to exit, your process just exits before you want it to.

Comment: Ah I undertand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx reading this article tells you that the `WaitForExit()` does not keep the program alive, it just waits for the associated program to exit. If the associated program(unzip.exe here) exits, you will *not* be able to stop the `unzip.exe` program from exiting.

Answer (score 0):

`Process.WaitForExit` makes *your* application wait for the *other* process to exit. It has no impact at all on the started process itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create bat file and insert there command to wait (using command timeout or other solution from thread [Sleeping in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-batch-file)

And start in Process yours bat file