# How to Compare output of a command dynamically in batch program

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I want to poll the state of my android device dynamically using adb in a batch file.

I know that the command "adb devices" or "fastboot devices" gives me the the device id of the device in the respective state and are mutually exclusive. I want to put one of these commands in an if, so that I can judge by comparing the output which state my device is in.

I have seen some if usage in batch file in other posts here, but they weren't helpful as I wasn't able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has a command called `watch`, which is perfect for what you want to do.  You can simply:

```
watch adb devices
```

This will refresh the command every 2 seconds (I think?) by default, but the delay is configurable using a command switch.

In Windows, I would probably use something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5483958/1003560