# Typing a Text File One Line At A Time

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script that can fetch data from various files on a drive, and that bit is all working fine.
The problem is that I would like the contents of the file to be typed to the cmd one line at a time.

A bit like this:

```
Hello, this is the first line of the text file
```

1 second pause

```
And this is the second line
```

etc.

I've tried using a for command, but I could only get that to repeat the first line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advanced! -Luke

Comment: show some codes. no one here is magician to know how u've done things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeout` is in Vista and above

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
echo %%a
timeout /t 1 /nobreak
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find many ways how to delay execution of script depending on your needs in this post:

[Sleeping in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-batch-file)

Hope it helps.