# Clearr cmd after sending text

Tags: text, cmd, line, clr, typing

I've found this small script. And my question is, how can I clear cmd (cls) after every line?

So when the first line is done, it clears cmd and the next line shows up.

Can anyone help? :)

```
@echo off
:: Ghost typer
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set lines=6


set "line1=Twinkle twinkle little star"
set "line2=How I wonder what you are"
set "line3=Up above the world so high"
set "line4=Like a diamond in the sky"
set "line5=Twinkle twinkle little star"
set "line6=How I wonder what you are"


for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

for /L %%a in (1,1,%lines%) do set num=0&set "line=!line%%a!"&call :type

pause>nul
goto :EOF

:type
set "letter=!line:~%num%,1!"
set "delay=%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%"
set "delay=%delay:~-6%"
if not "%letter%"=="" set /p "=a%bs%%letter%" <nul

:: adjust the 3 in the line below: higher is faster typing speed

for /L %%b in (1,10,%delay%) do rem
if "%letter%"=="" echo.&goto :EOF
set /a num+=1
goto :type
```

Thanks!

Comment: the command, you search for is just `cls` Do you need help with where to put it?

Comment: @Stephan I know the command, I just need help where to put it

Answer (score 6):

put your `cls` there, where typing a new line starts (just before the `call :type`):

```
for /L %%a in (1,1,%lines%) do set num=0&set "line=!line%%a!"&cls&call :type
                                                               ^---- here
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to cls with a little delay?

Comment: yes, but how, depends on your OS: `timeout`, `sleep`, `ping`. See here for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-batch-file

Comment: And where do I put that?

Comment: Where do you want it to be? Maybe just before the `cls`?