# How do I do a milisecond delay in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, time, delay

I was wondering if there is a delay command in a batch file that can delay for less than a second (like 0.2 seconds). As of right now I only know of the `timeout (seconds)` which can only delay for a minimum of 1 second. I would appreciate any help :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-batch-file/21941058#21941058

Comment: `start "" /wait /min /realtime mshta "javascript:setTimeout(function(){close();},500)"` - this will wait 500 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, there isn't a very "good" way of doing this. Some might suggest using the ping command, which is actually possible to give miliseconds of delay, but this is using the wrong tool for the wrong place.
It would be must better to write a code in C (or any other languages with this feature) and run it on batch. Try the program at the link below.

https://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/millisleep.php

Comment: Please do not use third party links as answers to questions, instead use the comment section, if you have sufficient reputation to do so, to provide resources for the OP.